# How to count unlabeled balls and labeled boxes case?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How to count unlabeled balls and labeled boxes case

each box can have more than one balls or some box may have no balls

use example , 10 labeled boxes, 8 unlabeled balls

welcome to use polynomial counting

better have closed formula or generating function

would like to know Prob(a labelled box have 3 balls) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, if you have n boxes then each ball has a 1/n chance of being in each box. So if you have k balls and you want the probability a box has x balls in it, the answer is given by the binomial distribution: $^kC_x(\frac{1}{n})^x(1-\frac{1}{n})^{k-x}$

Comment: That looks like labelled balls.  In addition the number of balls in a box is not independent of the number in another box.

Comment: The balls aren't labelled in this case. As for the dependency that has to exist unless I've misinterpreted your question. Otherwise if I have a finite number of balls and boxes of course there's a dependency! (as a simple example if all of the balls are in one box, then all the other boxes have to be empty)

Answer (score 0):

["Stars and bars"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) will tell that with $n=10$ labelled boxes and $k=8$ unlabelled balls there are $k$ stars and $n-1$ bars so the number is $${k+n-1 \choose k}= {17 \choose 8} = 24310$$ possibilities.

Comment: box can have no balls or box can have more than one balls

Comment: @StateBoy: yes: no balls in a box is two bars with no stars between; more than one ball is stars with no bars between